# Troubleshooting GNOME Interface Unresponsiveness after Deleting DNF Cache on Fedora 39

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome, dnf

I encountered a problem with my Linux system running Fedora 39 after executing the following command:

```bash
sudo rm -rfv /var/cache/dnf/*
```

I know now that I should have used it

```bash
dnf clean all
```

Initially, I believed these were just temporary files. However, after this action, the GNOME interface ceased to function entirely, and the following image appeared:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foflR.jpg)

Furthermore, the logs generated by the command:

```bash
journalctl -xe
```

are provided here:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtHNc.jpg)

I attempted the following solutions without success:

1- Update DNF packages:

```bash
sudo dnf update
sudo dnf upgrade
sudo dnf reinstall "*"
```

2- Create a new user to test for potential GNOME configuration issues, but this did not resolve the problem.

I am seeking guidance on how to address and resolve this issue. Any assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.